# minicom output disappears inside tmux on choose-tree

Tags: tmux

If minicom is started inside tmux; and the tmux pane with minicom is active then:

- if I switch client by 'switch-client -l' - minicom output is ok;
- but if by 'choose-tree -NZs' - minicom output disappears like by minicom command 'ctrl-a, c' ("Clears the screen" from the man page);

If another tmux pane or window is active - minicom output is ok.

Any solution to keep minicom output in all cases?

tmux 2.7 inside Konsole Version 17.12.3
OpenSuse Leap 15.0, kernel 4.12.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is '-Z' argument in 'choose-tree -NZs' command. By this argument, the pane zooms what brings to clearing screen. Replacing the command by 'choose-tree -Ns' solves the problem.